# Read Unread SMS on Windows Mobile 5.0

Tags: sms, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-5.0

How to read unread SMS in windows mobile 5.0?

I saw the reference link that is send and receive SMS, but I ask how to read an existing SMS in inbox for particularly "UNREAD" SMS?

Answer (score 0):

This might help

http://blogs.msdn.com/raffael/archive/2008/09/08/mapi-on-windows-mobile-6-programmatically-retrieve-mail-body-sample-code.aspx

You will probably need to use some native code to access the CE MAPI api to retrieve the messages from the message store.

Alternatively I think mobile in the hand .net components by Peter Foot provides managed wrappers that may do what you need:

http://inthehand.com/content/Mobile.aspx